# Mergesort Seg Fault CONFUSION C++

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am in the middle of writing code for merge sort however, I have a seg fault that I have no idea where the origin is. Here is the code:

```
// Merge Sort Implementation
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &v, int left, int mid, int right) {
  int nL = mid - left + 1;
  int nR = right - mid;
  vector<int> L(nL);
  vector<int> R(nR);

  for (int i = 0; i < nL; ++i) {
    L[i] = v[left + i];
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < nR; ++j) {
    R[j] = v[mid + 1 + j];
  }
}
void merge_sort(vector<int> &v, int start, int end) {
  if (start <= end) {
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    merge_sort(v, start, mid);
    merge_sort(v, mid + 1, end);
    // merge(v, start, mid, end);
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<int> v{2, 1, 5, 7, 9};
  /* vector<int> v{1,   5,  6,  7,  16, 327, 717, 76, 1,  6,
                177, 17, 53, 69, 2,  0,   4,   3,  32, 27}; */
  int size = v.size();
  merge_sort(v, 0, size - 1);

  for (int i : v) {
    printf("%d ", i);
  }
}
```

Commented out parts that I thought would cause this issue including all parts that access elements in the vector. I have also commented out the call to the merge fcn. The problem seems to come from merge_sort().

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Most probably problems accessing arrays out of valid indexing boundaries, whatever...

Comment: `if (start <= end) {` Not sure if you want start to ever equal end. Without debugging I believe you get infinite recursion when it does.

Comment: "_I have no idea where the origin is_": To figure something like this out you use a debugger or alternatively you compile the program with e.g. the address sanitizer enabled, which will tell you where the issue is, namely that you have an infinite recursion: https://godbolt.org/z/P5KaKx96q

Comment: you are getting infinite recursion in you sort function

Answer (score 1):

Your low end sort never terminates

```
 `if (start <= end) {`
```

is always true since start is 0 and end never gets below 0. So you recurse forever and blow up your stack

You need

```
if (start < end) {`
```